# How to apply EthFilter to specific address?

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3j, java, websocket

In web3.js, we can apply event filter something like below:

```
 this.event = this.Contract.events.MyEvent({
     filter: { address: "0xAccountAddress" },
 })
```

In Web3J, it is translated to

```
EthFilter eventFilter = new EthFilter(
    DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST,
    DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST,
    mContract.getContractAddress()
);
eventFilter.addSingleTopic(EventEncoder.encode(Contract.MY_EVENT));
```

But, how to pass specific address in the event like `filter` in above web3.js example?

Comment: The contract address `mContract.getContractAddress()` is the specific address filter! Basically you querying the node to return all events for this given account address

Comment: @GregJeanmart No i want to filter from specific address. For example, consider this event for some game playing between two parties. Then I want to filter event only for those two people only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, let's say you have a smart contract deployed on the address `CONTRACT_ADDRESS` which can trigger different type of events

**Event definitions:**

```
event GameStarted(bytes32 indexed gameId, address indexed player1, address indexed player2);
event PlayerMoved(bytes32 indexed gameId, address indexed player);
event GameEnded(bytes32 indexed gameId, address indexed player1, address indexed player2);
```

When an event is triggered from a smart contract during a transaction, this event  is added in an event log (part of the blockchain global state). The event log can be queried using one or several filters (smart contract address, block number range, topics).

The keyword `indexed` means that the event will be added to a special data structure called `topics` in the event logs. Consequently, it is possible to query the event log on those event parameters.

An event definition accept up to three indexed parameters.

An event is internally structured like this:

- **address**: the address of the contract (intrinsically provided by Ethereum);
- **topics[0]**: keccak(EVENT_NAME+"("+EVENT_ARGS.map(canonical_type_of).join(",")+")") (canonical_type_of is a function that simply returns the canonical type of a given argument, e.g. for uint indexed foo, it would return uint256). If the event is declared as anonymous the topics[0] is not generated;
- **topics[n]**: EVENT_INDEXED_ARGS[n - 1] (EVENT_INDEXED_ARGS is the series of EVENT_ARGS that are indexed);
- **data**: abi_serialise(EVENT_NON_INDEXED_ARGS) (EVENT_NON_INDEXED_ARGS is the series of EVENT_ARGS that are not indexed, abi_serialise is the ABI serialisation function used for returning a series of typed values from a function, as described above).

[Source](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html#events)

Let's go back to the Java part, the following code demonstrates how to filter only the events of type `GameStarted` where `player2=MY_ADDRESS` from the smart contract `CONTRACT_ADDRESS` within the block range [`BLOCK_n`, `BLOCK_m`]:

```
EthFilter eventFilter = new EthFilter(
    BLOCK_n, // filter: from block
    BLOCK_m, // filter: to block
    CONTRACT_ADDRESS // filter: smart contract address
);
eventFilter.addSingleTopic(EventEncoder.encode(Contract.GameStarted)); // filter: event type (topic[0])
eventFilter.addOptionalTopics(null, null, MY_ADDRESS); // filter: event parameters (gameId: no filter, player1: no filter, player2: filter)
```